# Can I detect movement of a browser window from one screen to another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multiple-monitors

In JavaScript, I can get the screen's height with `window.screen.height`. Now, if I have dual monitors, and the two monitors are different sizes, and I move the browser window from one monitor to the other, is there any way to detect that, beyond polling the window size at intervals in time?

Comment: Is there any javascript functionality that you wish to achieve or is it just in terms of presentation? If you have no business logic and only presentation you could look into css viewports: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the question, I meant "screen height".

Comment: You can try to make use of media queries, specifically `device-height` and `device-width` rules. You can attach event listeners to be notified when those values changes. Maybe it can help you. Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#device-width).

Answer (score 3):

There's no reliable way to do this, `screen.height` will always return the height of the primary monitor, doesn't matter how many monitors you have, so that's not going to help at all.

Using screenX/Y doesn't really help either, as there are no indications of when one screen ends and another begins, and trying to calculate it would be hard as there's no guarantee the user starts out with the browser at the top left in one of the screens, or that the browser takes up the entire screen, and you can't get the dimensions for any other monitor than the primary screen, so there's no way to know the size of the other screens.

In other words, it's going to be hard to do this, if not impossible, and any solution will probably not be very reliable or portable, so you're better of just sticking with the browser window and detecting changes to that, which is easy and generally all you need.

Comment: Why cant you use screen.availWidth? Doesn't it give you the combined width of both screens? Couldn't you subtract the width of the main screen to determine the width of the second screen? You could then make an educated guess at the second screens height just by knowing standard screen resolution sizes.

Comment: @GaryHayes - I have four screens, and `screen.availWidth` only gives me `1920`, which is the width of the primary screen, as noted in my answer, screen doesn't give you dimensions for anything other than the primary screen.

Comment: Okay. I only have one screen. Is there a way to change focus to other screen with javascript and get availWidth from it?

Comment: Not sure if that was the case when this was written, but if so, then things have changed. In Angular, screen.width gives the monitor width of the current monitor the browser window is in, regardless if it is the primary monitor or not. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, as long as the monitor the user is switching over to has different dimensions.

I use Angular, so this is how I do it.

Important notes before the code:

1. `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` is the size of your app's space within the browser. Whereas `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` is the size of the device (such as your monitor or laptop screen) that the browser running your app is on. So, if you listen to changes to `window.screen.height` and `window.screen.width`, you can detect when a user has dragged the browser to another monitor, as long as that monitor has either a different height and or width.
2. You can use either `screen.width` and `screen.height` or `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`, either will get you the same. We'll use `screen` instead of `window.screen` since it is shorter.
3. The `window:resize` event at least in Angular gets triggered not just when a user expands or contracts the browser window, but also when a change in a monitor's or device's screen dimensions occurs.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  screenHeight: number
  screenWidth: number

  constructor() { 
    this.screenHeight = screen.height
    this.screenWidth = screen.width
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
  
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize() {
    // if user has switched from one monitor size to another, then screen.height and screen.width will have changed
    if(this.screenHeight != screen.height || this.screenWidth != screen.width) {
      console.log("Congratulations, this must be a different monitor/device")
      this.screenWidth = screen.width 
      this.screenHeight = screen.height
    }
  }
}
```